# Docusign event notifications

Tags: docusignapi

I am implementing a listener for Docusign event notifications.  For each new event Docusign sends a new xml serialized DosuSignEnvelopeInformation object. My question is, does that object include only new changed statuses or if for example one of the recipients status has not changed it will still be included. Also, since a change to one of the recipients status does not necessarily change the envelope status, will the notification always include the envelope status ?

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend taking a look at the XSD: https://www.docusign.net/api/3.0/schema/dsx.xsd

The type sent by connect is  DocuSignEnvelopeInformation, which consists of EnvelopeStatus and DocumentPDF objects, both of which have their schema defined in this XSD. In short the connect XML is a snapshot of the envelope at the time the notification is sent to you - the snapshot will include all recipient information.

In the sandbox environment you can enable a test DS Connect configuration with logging enabled to see what types of messages you will be receiving.

Answer (score 1):

Absolutely correct and keep in mind that to save space in the demo environment we don't include the PDF byte stream in the log as it has no logic, meaning it's just a bunch of bytes. If you want to see it you can use webhook.com (free) or some other tool like that.

Answer (score 1):

The Connect Service and the related "eventNotification" node in the API are event-driven. They don't publish events, but rather, the complete *current* status of the envelope, which includes envelope status, recipient status for all recipients, and more.  The service *always publishes the **current** status*, so two "near" events might trigger one coalesced status publication, or two close publications.  However, the last publication will include the latest changes.  If you get a "republished" status (such as due to failed acknowledgement or directly triggered), it again is the *current* status, not the "old" status at the time of the original publication.